# Using awk, how can I find the max value in one column, print it; then print the match value in another column

Tags: if-statement, awk, max

Let's say I have this data:

```
1  text1  1   1   5
2  text2  2   2   10 
3  text3  3   3   15
4  text4  4   4   50
5  text5  5   5   25
```

I obtain the max value of column #5 with this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {a=0} {if ($5>0+a) a=$5} END{print a}' data.txt
```

My question is how do I add more parameters in that code in order to find the associated value in whatever column I choose (but just one)? For example, I want to find the max value of column #5 and the associated value from column #2

The output I want is:

```
50 text4
```

I don't know how to add more parameters in order to obtain the match value.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output when 2 rows have the same max value for column 5.

Answer (score 5):

Right way to do this is this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'NR==1 || $5>max { max=$5; val=$2 } END { print max, val }' file

50 text4
```

This sets `max=$5` and `val=$2` for the first record or when `$5` is greater than `max` variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you find a new max then save *both* the new max and the associated value from column #2.

One idea, along with some streamlining of the current code:

```
$ awk '$5>(a+0) { a=$5; col2=$2 } END {print a, col2}' data.txt
50 text4
```

**NOTE:**

- this assumes that at least one value in column #5 is positive; if all values in column #5 are negative then `$5>(a+0)` will always be false and `a` (and `col2`) will never get set, which in turn means `print a, col2` will print a line with a single space; a better solution would be to set `a` to the first value processed and then go from there (see anubhava's answer for an example)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `sort`

```
% sort -nk 5 file | tail -1 | awk '{print $5, $2}'
50 text4
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `sort` + `awk` option here. With GNU `sort` sorting the file by 5th column and then piping its result to `awk` where reading very first line which is containing max value and printing it, exiting from program to save time of `awk`.

```bash
sort -s -rnk5 file1 | awk 'FNR==1{print $NF,$2;exit}'
50 text4
```